# Nested form: passing values

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm a bit at a loss here with Symfony nested forms..

I have Events and RoleEntries i.e. the role that people or organizations can have for an event...

So I have an EventType form, with a nested RoleEntryType:

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                function (FormEvent $event) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();
                    $data = $event->getData();


                    $form->add('roleEntries', 'collection', array(
                        'type'         => new RoleEntryType($data),
                        'allow_add'    => true,
                        'allow_delete' => true
                        ));
                }
            )
```

the $data variable is caught by the RoleEntryType constructor:

```
$this->data=$data;
```

And I try to add a hidden field (since the user should not modify it, in the field):

```
 ->add($this->targetScope, 'hidden',  array('data'=>$this->data))
```

At this point, Symfony is not happy because it cannot convert the $data to string

*An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class IH\EventManagerBundle\Entity\Event could not be converted to string") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13.*

so I try just to give it an Id

```
 ->add($this->targetScope, 'hidden',  array('data'=>$this->data->getId()))
```

But it doesn't work either because a string is not enough, it wants a fully fledged event:

*Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to IH\EventManagerBundle\Entity\RoleEntry::setEvent() must be an instance of IH\EventManagerBundle\Entity\Event, string given, called in /Users/MTP/Documents/dev/MTP/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 410 and defined*

So I guess I'm doing it all wrong....

help!

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/bjo3rnf/4061232 for how to create what you want. see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1946 and then https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/8112 for future development.

Answer (score 0):

$data contains the form data, so you need to extract your field value and pass it as value for your hidden field:

```
$form->add('targetScope', 'hidden',  array('data' => $data['field_name']));
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply but I don't get it...

If I do a `get_type($data)` I do get: 
`"IH\EventManagerBundle\Entity\Event"`

So that's what I do when I do:
`->add($this->targetScope, 'hidden',  array('data'=>$this->data->getId()))`

But I get the error that setEvent() does not accept a string as a parameter...

Comment: In this case you need to send as value directly $data, and how @DonCallisto mentioned, create a __toString() method in your Event entity.

Answer (score 0):

Without change your initial implantation, just add a `__to string()` magic method to Event entity and all should work as expected

Something like

```
Class Event
{
    [...]
    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Of course `$this->name;` should be changed accordingly to your object properties.

If you need, when posting the form, to recreate (or take from db) an entity object, take a look to [DataTransformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

Comment: I think he wants to retrieve the entity itself, not just the name.

Comment: @user2268997 is pretty clear that error there is that he's trying to pass the whole entity but symfony2 form component expects a string to render that field. Even if you try to render a entity, you need to implemented that method. OP could be "in trouble" when he need to bind submitted that but he could easily bypass that changing form field type or using DataTransformer

Comment: I know what the error is, I'm saying what he [probably] **wants** is to create an 'entity' field type that is hidden, which can be done using transformers. see comment on original post.

Comment: @user2268997:
Well you're right, but I can't believe that this is not implemented directly into Symfony, I mean, how come the link between my form and my nested form is not made?

Comment: @PaulDuboi error isn't because form are not "linked". Read my answer carefully

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies,

So using DataTransformer or creating a new field type (EntityHidden) both work... however, my problem stemed from something I forgot in my code which forced me to handle this in the FormType rather than in the entity...

Simply, there is no need to pass the primary key of the entity corresponding to the nesting form (Event) over to the nested form (RoleEntryType)... if I tell my Event entity setter that it should write a reference of the event in the new RoleEntry:

```
public function addRoleEntry(
{
    $this->roleEntries[] = $roleEntry;

    $roleEntry->setEvent($this);

    return $this;
}
```

Sorry if my question wasn't clear and thanks for taking the time to answer!